# Is it possible to have a user without access to code in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Online, is it possible to have a user that can access things such as the product backlog, but are unable to access the code (read or write)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Permissions are quite granular in VSO.

There's no default group with those permissions, so you'll need to create a new group in the admin pages. Give that new group permissions to the work items, etc (look at the settings for the contributors group to see an example) and in the version control tab ensure that all the permissions are set to deny for each of the available options.

After that, just add users to that group and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is also available by default in the (free) [Visual Studio Online Stakeholder plan](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-user-plans-vs#AdditionalPageSections_2) that was recently released.

Comment: The stakeholders can "View, add, and modify items on the backlog".  Is it possible to limit this to view only, or view and add but not modify?